# "undefined reference to my function" Android Ndk

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a prebuild so file in which there are two function and im trying to call a C function name as myFunction() in a C class from the so file in other project in C class the 
problem is when i compile the project using the ndk-build command it will give this error "undefined reference to my function".

**This is the prebuild so "c class"**

```
int myFunction()
{
    int number = 10;
    return number;
}

jstring Java_com_example_compileso_MainActivity_myFunction(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis)
{
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "String from C class!");
}
```

**I'm calling the myFunction() in other project.
This is the C class where im calling the my function.**

```
void newFunction()
{
    int nResult = myFunction();

    printf("%s", str);
}
```

**I create a folder lib in jni folder and place the prebuild so file & also make a Android.mk file
This is the Android.mk file in lib folder.**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libndkfunction-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libndkfunction.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**And this is the my project Android.mk file**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# Here we give our module name and source file(s)
LOCAL_MODULE    := ndkfun
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ndkfun.c

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libndkfunction-prebuilt        
 LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/jni/include                
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

java class of my project.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    static 
      {
        System.loadLibrary("ndkfun");
      }

     private native String mynewFunction();
     public native int myFunction();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setText(mynewFunction());
        setContentView(textview);

    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must declare the `myFunction` function in your java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  public native int myFunction();

}
```

Comment: Is `myFunction` returning a jstring or a jint (there are both signatures in your code)

Comment: its returing a int value not jint. and this time i'm print the value

Comment: i'm accessing a simple c function that return a int value from so file and i call this c function in new project in c class

Comment: So you need to chnge the signature from `jstring Java_com_example_compileso_MainActivity_myFunction` to `jint Java_com_example_compileso_MainActivity_myFunction`

Comment: its not a java function its a simple c function and i'm trying to access the c function

Comment: So if it's not your code, you wont be able to access it directly. You first need to create a JNI binding (from java to C) and then, inside this C binding, call the `myFunction` from the prebuild library. (and don't forget the #include)

Comment: its my code and i will send u all the code where u can check easily

Comment: This is the link where u can download this project and solve my this problem Link 1  of my project https://www.dropbox.com/s/ce5j7p8s589y1f4/compileMultiSo.rar?dl=0  Link 2 Prebuild so file https://www.dropbox.com/s/u6egor77cnwwzwt/compileSo.rar?dl=0